# Apache2 redirecting to main site

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to host multiple websites off a digitalocean droplet using apache2's virtualhosts.
I have a config file for the main one, (pcnerd19.com) and one for the other, (efferri.ga). Whenever I type efferri.ga in firefox though, it just redirects back to pcnerd19.com I've restarted apache2, and made sure both sites are enabled. The is an index file at the root of efferri.ga as well. Here are my config files.

pcnerd19.com:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName pcnerd19.com
ServerAlias www.pcnerd19.com
ServerAdmin ruby@pcnerd19.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress1
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pcnerd19.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pcnerd19.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/wordpress1>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<IfModule>
```

efferri.ga:

```
<VirtualHost *:83>
ServerName efferri.ga
ServerAlias www.efferri.ga
ServerAdmin ruby@pcnerd19.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/efferri
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It is worth mentioning I used certbot to get an ssl certificate on pcnerd19.com, and my droplet is running Debian.

Answer (score 0):

From this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apache-vhost-issue-two-domains-second-redirects-to-first) where someone had a similar problem, this answer might help:

> When looking at your VirtualHost configuration, you’re setting a ServerAlias that defines the www. access point for each domain, but you’re missing a DNS entry on both domains that points www. to your domain. Since the DNS record isn’t set, Apache will handle it the best way it knows how, which may or may not be correct.
>
> So what I would recommend doing is adding an A entry to each domains’ DNS records. The A entry should point to the same IP that your domain points to (i.e. the public IP of the Droplet).
>
> So www should be an A entry that points to 46.101.19.243 in your case. Since it looks like your using DigitalOcean for your DNS, you can make these changes through their control panel and the updates should take effect pretty quickly. If they don’t, you may need to clear your browsers cache and then try to access your domains again.

Comment: I checked and I do have www pointed to the right ip for both domains.

Comment: Can you check what happens on your console when you get redirected? Also what have you set in your host file?